# jQuery nodelist -- how to iterate

Tags: javascript, jquery

i mean i wanna iterate manually using a for-loop or something. but this piece of code i came up with seems to be not working. i like combining javascript with jquery since jquery is not my cup of tea for major projects. i don't know much jquery either, i would say I'm beginning to learn, though. how do you iterate over a nodelist in jquery is the question i have for all those jquery fans this time. is it similar to the javascript way? anyway this is what i have come up with (the code of a beginner).

```
$("sn"[i]).fadeIn();
```

`$("sn"[i])` the part which failed, according to google chrome.

Comment: you need to provide more context on what is `i` and what is `sn`

Comment: your code is syntactically incorrect

Comment: @user3322451 Post your html will make your question more clear.

Comment: I don't see how your code would ever work in a "Javascript way", as you call it, either. Update your question with relevant information e.g. HTML example, and we can see for ourselves

Comment: @ArunPJohny: Actually it's not. If `i` is `0`, then `"sn"[i]` return `"s"`.

Comment: .snSomething is a class name assigned to different elements. so that makes it a list

Comment: What do you expect `"sn"[i]` to be? A string? A single element? A list of elements? Is this code inside a loop? Show surrounding code.

Comment: @FelixKling yes Missed it completely :(

Comment: You probably could have avoided a lot of confusion if you just use a proper class selector in your example, e.g. `'.sn'`, instead of `'sn'`, and if you didn't use the term node list. A node list is a specific object return by functions such as `getElementsByTagName`. So if you say you want to iterate over a node list, it rather sounds like you want to iterate over a specific object, not *select* elements with that class in the document.

Comment: What a splendidly peculiar question! I can't help liking it a bit. (Not upvoting it, though.)

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
$("sn[" + i + "]").fadeIn();
```

Comment: r u sure? coz that's the same thing i entered, i fear.

Comment: sorry, see my edit, I hit enter too fast :)

Comment: This would select all `sn` elements which have an attribute (whatever the value of `i` is).

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `sn` is a variable containing the node list, you are probably looking for

```
$(sn[i])
```

or

```
sn.eq(i)
```

if `sn` is already a jQuery object.

Comment: actually it's a class selector. would this still work?

Comment: i thought class selector works only if written within ""

Comment: @user3322451 do you mean `sn` is a class? then what is `i`

Comment: What is a class selector? You said you have a list of nodes which I assumed means you already have selected the elements you want to iterate over.

Comment: do you mean `$(".sn").eq(i]).fadeIn();`

Comment: @user3322451: I'm asking what is the class selector *in your code*.

Comment: ya, the contents of the class selector is in a NodeList object.

Comment: @user3322451 until you provide more context to the problem like the targeted markup and the complete script indicating the values for those variables we can only guess

Comment: @user3322451: A selector is always a string. It's not an object. It's really difficult to follow your problem. Please edit your question and add more context.

Comment: $("sn") -- if it were a single element

Comment: @user3322451: I'm not going to discuss this with you any further, because you seem to use the terminology incorrectly, which makes it extremely difficult to understand the problem.  Please edit your question and add the missing relevant part of your code.

Comment: but, if it was saved to a variable it's an object, isn't it? that's what i want. i want to iterate over the NodeList object with this variable.

Comment: @user3322451: Yes, if you had `var sn = $(...);` then `sn` is a jQuery object, and you can access the `i`-th DOM element in the selection with `sn[i]`. Which selector you used is irrelevant.

Comment: what about doing the same without said variable and using a class selector?

Comment: assuming i have many elements with the same class...

Comment: @user3322451: You mean `$('.class').eq(i)` or `$('.class')[i]`? You can do that, but it would search for all `.class` elements in each iteration which is quite inefficient.

Comment: @user3322451, that'd be `$(".sn").fadeIn()`

Comment: i thought $('.class')[i] would work but chrome's showing this #<HTMLDivElement> has no method 'fadeIn'

Comment: @user3322451: That's because if you access a jQuery object like that you get back the **DOM element** at that index, not a jQuery object. If you want a jQuery object, use `$('.class').eq(i)`.

Comment: @user3322451 as I said if `sn` is the class and `i` is the index then `$(".sn").eq(i]).fadeIn();`

Comment: if it were JavaScript, i could have used `document.getElementsByClassName("a")[i];` what's the jquery replacement for that?

Comment: @user3322451: `$('.a')[i]`.

Comment: $('.sn')[i].fadeOut(); is not working. can i upload the full code?

Comment: @user3322451 if you want to use fadeIn()  then `$('.a').eq(i).fadeIn()`

Comment: or is it because i placed jquery before my main js file or anything related to dom loading?

Comment: @user3322451: Of course `$('.sn')[i].fadeOut();` is not working, because `fadeOut` is a **jQuery** method and `$('.sn')[i]` returns a **DOM element**. You asked for the equivalent of `document.getElementsByClassName("a")[i]` and that's what I gave you. `document.getElementsByClassName("a")[i].fadeOut()` doesn't work either. If you want to use a jQuery method, then use `$('.a').eq(i)`, because it returns a **jQuery object**. This is the fourth time (including my answer), that I mention `.eq`. How often do I have to repeat myself?

Comment: but it's still ahowing cannot call method 'fadeIn' of undefined.:-(

Comment: @user3322451: Then you have a different problem, because `.eq` **never** returns `undefined`. Since you refuse to update your question and add relevant context information, there is nothing we can do.

Comment: okay, mate. i'll be back after 24 hours. okay?

Answer (score 1):

I think you mean that "sn" is the selector for the nodes, in that case:

```
$("sn").fadeIn();
```

This works on all the elements that match the selector, jQuery will do the iteration. However if you want to select all elements that have the 'sn' class you should prefix the selector with a `.` like so: `".sn"`

if you want to loop manually try:

```
$(".sn").each(function(i) {
  $(this) // do some magic with the individual element here
});
```

See more on iterating with each here:
https://api.jquery.com/each/