# jquery fadeOut not working - update

Tags: javascript, jquery

i mean i wanna iterate manually using a for-loop or something. but this piece of code i came up with seems to be not working. i like combining javascript with jquery since jquery is not my cup of tea for major projects. i don't know much jquery either, i would say I'm beginning to learn, though. how do you iterate over a nodelist in jquery is the question i have for all those jquery fans this time. is it similar to the javascript way? anyway this is what i have come up with (the code of a beginner).

HERE'S THE CODE //not working

```
$(".sn").[0].fadeOut();
$(".sn").[0].fadeOut("slow");
$(".sn").[0].fadeOut(3000);

        <div class="sn">
            content
        </div>
        <div class="sn sn-2">
            content
        </div>
        <div class="sn sn-3">
            content
        </div>
```

but $(".sn-2").fadeOut(); works like charm. why?

Comment: no why can't u help. i never said i prefer him?

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery nodelist -- how to iterate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21848001/jquery-nodelist-how-to-iterate)

Comment: ask me if any problem

Comment: Why you do not just use the each-method? https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/

Comment: it works according to conditions, not every elements.

Comment: $('.sn).eq(0).fadeOut(); will work

Answer (score 0):

in your code, you're trying to fadeout the .sn div three times.
try the following:

```
$.each($('.sn'), function(i, obj) { 
    $('.sn:eq(' + i + ')').fadeOut(3000); 
});
```

this way you'll be iterating over all the .sn class elements, and fade them out one by one by its index (:eq(i))

Comment: but that works for only one element? i want to iterate using `i`

Comment: `$.each($('.sn'), function(i, obj) { $('.sn')[i].fadeOut(3000); });`

Comment: why doesn't `$(".sn").[0].fadeOut();` work while `$(".sn-2").fadeOut();` does?

Comment: `$.each($('.sn'), function(i, obj) { 
    $('.sn:eq(' + i + ')').fadeOut(3000); 
});`

Answer (score 0):

```
 $('.sn').each(function(){
     $(this).fadeOut('slow');
   });
```

Comment: jain, how can i iterate using i?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are looking for something like this?
It will fade out each sn element within a loop.

I also updated the html to make it more consistent

```
   for(var i=0; i < $(".sn").length; i+=1){
        $(".sn-"+[i]).fadeOut(3000);
   }
```

HTML

```
<div class="sn sn-0"> content </div>
<div class="sn sn-1"> content </div>
<div class="sn sn-2"> content </div>
```

Further you need to know, that `$(".sn")` represents an object, which does not have any property [0] which you are trying to access with your code `($(".sn").[0]`)
So to make this work you have to access the element you want to trigger by any event like this $(".sn")[0].

Best

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$(".sn:first").fadeOut();
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try this also :

```
for(var i=0; i < $(".sn").length; i+=1){
        $(".sn").eq(i).fadeOut(3000);
   }
```